# onpopstate isn't always triggered

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, dom-events, browser-history

I have an **angular** project where im trying to capture the back button event, to trigger my own function.

I'm using `onpopstate`, from `window` (*js*) and `platformLocation` (*angular*), and the function isn't always triggered.

I have a login which redirects to my pages, and i can pass in two ways.

- As a new user, in the register form in my app. In this case the function is triggered
- Access with an existing account, to any page. In this case is where the function never works. In fact, if I go to the register page, it doesn't work neither.

I tried with `window.onbeforeunload` too, and always execute it, but when I try to redirect to another page (is what I want to do) and prevent the default navigation, isn't working.

Do you have some idea about what is happening?

**I appreciate your help**

**EDIT**

This is the main code in my service.

Service code

```
@Injectable()
export class BackService {

    constructor(
        private _platformLocation: PlatformLocation
    ) {
        vm.setBackEvent();
    }

    /**
     * NAvigation from browser
     */
    setBackEvent() {
        const vm = this;
        // JS ** this trigger the function but dont navigate
        // window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        //     console.log('onbbeforeunload');
        //     location.href = url;
        //     return ;
        // };

        // JS  ** this doesnt work always
        // window.onpopstate = (e) => {
        //     console.log('window onpopstate');
        //     location.href = url;
        // }


        // Angular ** his doesnt work always
        this._platformLocation.onPopState = (e: LocationChangeListener) => {
             console.log('PlatformLocation onpopstate');
             location.href = url;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing your code would help. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Please, post your code and what you have done till now.

Answer (score 1):

I respond myself

i found this hack to trigger the `popstate` function always.

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) {
   // ... Some code ... 
}
history.pushState({}, ''); // this makes the function always works
```

thanks anyway